# TouchPanView no more available

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for the Jquery plugin "TouchPanView",

but on the official [site](http://www.consulenza-web.com/jquery/touchpanview/)

i can only find a demo.

Where can i download the plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.consulenza-web.com/jquery/touchpanview/jquery.touchpanview.js

http://www.consulenza-web.com/jquery/touchpanview/jquery.touchpanview.css

But it seems developing was stopped years ago. Look at this plugin: https://github.com/peachananr/panorama_viewer, - it might fit for your task.